# How to display a next day date?

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET

Using DatagridView, In a Datagrid View values are displaying like this

ID Date

```
001 23/02/2009
001 24/02/2009
001 25/02/2009
```

I want to display a date in a textbox after 25/02/2009

I Used a sql query for getting a next date

```
Select CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(dd, 1, MAX(SDate)), 103) AS SDate from tb_Sched_Add
```

the above query is displaying a next date 26/02/2009 in the textbox, but it is taking a some second to display. There is any way in program itself getting a last value of the row (date) in datagridview and display the next date.

Need vb.net code help

Comment: How are you populating the DataGridView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a date in your VB.NET code you can use the [`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method:

```
Dim latestDate As DateTime = SomeMethodThatGetsLastDate()
Dim nextDate As DateTime = latestDate.AddDays(1)
```

Perhaps you have populated a list with the existing items, so that you can obtain the latest date from that data?

Answer (score 0):

THis option is nice, tho then if you are to iterate with a button click, you are  likely to land into issues of not going more than 2 days in go. So a counter has to be in place to increment the value in AddDays(1) so replace "1" with counter++